# IDE for website development

Tags: software-rec, ide

This question has popped up in many open forum sites if you do a search term, but I think most of them are either talking about the remote explorer functionality or the design view.

However this is how I use a glorified text editor (Dreamweaver) in Windows and I was wondering if there is such functionality present in Linux. I use the site manager to keep a local copy of my PHP files, and on save they are uploaded to the remote server. It also keeps an eye out for all my changes, which i can commit when I decide im done with my process, Sort of like Eclipse.

Now there are IDEs or other software that do one or the other, however none that I found that perform both the tasks easily as one entity.

The question is, has anyone got comfortable using Linux as a prime PHP development platform to develop for remote servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're looking in the right place. The functionality you're asking about is primarily one that would be provided by [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) software. Specifically, use [distributed revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) software, such as [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29), [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial_%28software%29). Keep a repository on your local machine and one on your server. When you're satisfied with the changes, commit to your local repository, then push the changes to your server and update the checkout there. (You can script the whole chain, of course.)

The IDE part is only the icing on the cake: all you'd require from it is a convenient interface to the underlying version control software. Me being me, I'll recommend [Emacs](http://www.emacs.org/).

Comment: I suppose it is to do with habit, I am used to the way of Dreamweaver, its so hard changing habits to work in the way you are suggesting. However your solution sounds intresting, as I can still use an IDE to edit. and instead of using ftp to upload to server, I use svn to `ci` from local and `co` on server. But in essence dosent that slow things down a little?

Comment: @whoami: Your workflow wouldn't change: commit when satisfied, and have a script automatically check out on the server side. I do recommend switching away from svn and to a distributed VC system.

Comment: Ahhaaa I really understand now the idea of `distributed revision control` Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be usefull

HTML/PHP editors Blue Fish http://bluefish.linuxave.net

Thanks ...

Comment: I am using that at the moment, although it may have remote file explorer, it dosent have SVN (Not that i can see), therefore back to square one

Answer (score 0):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) has an SVN plugin. I've been happy with it for HTML and PHP editing, as well as some limited Groovy/Grails work.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Aptana Studio 3, which is an IDE built on Eclipse

Try it out, it's nice

It has a GIT-plugin which is the standard, probably you can also find a plugin for other revision control systems

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Quanta Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanta_Plus). It has been a great web design tool for for me since years.

Whenever I do a change to my local code, then Quanta detects the files that have been edited and lets you put only those files to the server via ftp. And if you add a new file to the project directory you can scan the project for new files.